# felm doesn't work with broom::augment/purrr but works with tidy

Tags: r, purrr, broom

I'm trying to run regressions within a nested data frame [as described here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/). For my purposes, I'm using `felm` from the `lfe` package because I have many levels of fixed effects.

If I re-do the example in the link above using `felm` instead of `lm`, it works for the most part until I try to use `broom::augment`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(gapminder)
library(lfe)

by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(continent, country) %>% 
  nest()

country_felm <- function(data){
  felm(lifeExp ~ year, data = data)
}

by_country <- by_country %>% 
    mutate(model = purrr::map(data, country_felm)
    )
```

Everything works up to this point except that I had to use a function instead of a formula in `purrr::map` in the last line of code, possibly another `felm` quirk.

Now if I try to use `broom` to extract the model output, it works for `glance` and `tidy`, but not for `augment`.

```
by_country %>% unnest(model %>% purrr::map(broom::glance))
by_country %>% unnest(model %>% purrr::map(broom::tidy))
by_country %>% unnest(model %>% purrr::map(broom::augment))
```

Trying to use `augment` results in the following error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(nrow(x)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `augment` is having trouble finding the data for the `data` argument, which is generally the dataset used for fitting.

The problem is easier to see if working with a single one of these models rather than all of them at once.

This doesn't work, with your given error:

```
augment(by_country$model[[1]])
```

But explicitly passing the data to the `data` argument does:

```
augment(by_country$model[[1]], data = by_country$data[[1]])
```

A work-around is therefore to pass the dataset to `augment` as the second argument.  This can be done via `purrr:map2`, looping through both the `model` and `data` columns at the same time.

```
by_country %>%
    unnest(model %>% purrr::map2(., data, augment))
```